# How to migrate mailboxes from google app  to local mail server

Tags: email, mac, g-suite, google

In my organization I have one MAC snow leopard server and 10 client systems.

I'm facing  a problem : 3 months ago in my organization I haven't any mail server. So I configured a google app server account [like example user mail id:mail.google.com/a/mymail.com]
All my employees mail boxes are stored on google servers. Two days ago I configured Mac mail server in my organization. How can I migrate mailboxes from Google server app to my own mail server? I hope my employees' mailboxes are very imp.. What should I do?

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Thanks a lot for your answers.

I still have this dilemma: in my mail server i didn't create any mailbox. If I create a mailbox in my mail server..on the way by using your software can I directly migrate mail boxes from Google app server to my MAC Snow Leopard mail server.

So, what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

Does the Mac mail server support IMAP also?

You could try IMAP copy http://home.arcor.de/armin.diehl/imapcopy/imapcopy.html

Answer (score 0):

I would go and setup the new mailboxes on the Mac Server and enabled IMAP.  Once you have done that you can use a tool like [ImapSync](http://www.linux-france.org/prj/imapsync/) to sync the two mailboxes.  Now the problem with ImapSync is its design for a single mailbox so I wrote a script called [imapbatch](https://github.com/zsiddique/imapbatch) which allows you to sync multiple mailboxes in a single go.